# How to allow only some specific chars in a string with jQuery

Tags: jquery, regex, string, escaping

I make users input some tags. These tags should contain only chars:

- `[a-z]`
- `[A-Z]`
- numbers `[0-9]`
- and the character `-`

If any other char is present, it should be removed from the string.

Is this possible? What is the fastest way to do that?

Comment: You can do this with JavaScript, no need for jQuery. What have you tried already? Hint hint:  String.[`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

Comment: Use regex to find and remove them with regular js.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need for jQuery:

```
str.replace(/[^a-z0-9\-]/ig,"");
```

Will remove anything that's not a letter, a number or a dash.

Answer (score 7):

You can assign a `keyup` event handler to the relevant `input` element, and filter the values using this code:

```
$("input").keyup(function(){
    var value = $(this).val().replace(/[^-a-zA-Z0-9]/g, "");
    $(this).val(value)
})
```

- `$("input")` selects all `input` elements. **Adjust this selector** to meet your wishes.
- The `keyup` event is triggered when the user releases a key.
- `$(this).val()` returns the value of the current input element.
- `[^-a-zA-Z0-9]` matches any invalid characters *(`/[^-a-z0-9]/i` has the same effect)*
- `/g` is the *global* flag, which means: Match every occurrence of the RegExp.
- `.replace(/.../g, "")` replaces all invalid characters by an empty string (=removes all invalid characters)
- `$(this).val(value)` changes the value of the current input element to a valid string.

Comment: … or use `gi` and just `a-z`. (Would that even be faster?)

Answer (score 2):

A simple regular expression replace:

```
userInputString.replace(/[^a-z0-9\-]/ig, "")
```